# IAB V3:Get product price in

Tags: android, google-play

I am implementing Google In-app Billing on my android game project. Now, I can purchase a product by using mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(). But how can I get the product price using v3 API? I found some methods online, but it doesn't work, the price is always null.

Here is my code:

```
public void IAB_getprice()
{       
    bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
            mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
        skuList.add("10001");
        skuList.add("10002");
        skuList.add("10003");
        skuList.add("10004");
        skuList.add("10005");
        skuList.add("10006");

        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList,mQueryFinishedListener);

        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

        try {
            Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
                    this.getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
            ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                    .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

            Log.e("In-app billing","skuDetails");
            if (null != responseList) {
                for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                    try {

                        SkuDetails d = new SkuDetails(thisResponse);
                        Log.e("In-app billing","thisResponse");

                        for (int i = 0; i < skuList.size(); i++) {
                            if (skuList.get(i).equals(d.getSku())) {
                                //price_list.set(i, d.getPrice());
                                payload[i] = d.getPrice();
                                product_id[i] = d.getSku();                                         
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("In-app billing","JSONException");
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("In-app billing","RemoteException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```